# Multi touch Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, multi-touch, delphi-xe3

I just ported to delphi XE3 for adding support for multi touch inputs, i played around with the built-in gesture feature, I added two TImages on form and in their OnGesture event i added code for moving them on detection of IGPan gesture. But i cant seem to move two images at once, why so? when a gesture is under progress on one TImage the other TImage ongesture event doesnt get fired. Is it supposed to work like this or i am doing it wrong.

Upon checking the TMS Multi touch component i saw that i can interact with more than one object at one i.e pan, zoom more than one object at once. Can someone guide me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 2):

The interactive gestures are based on the WM_Gesture message. There can only be one gesture going on at a time, that's a Windows limitation. You'd have to use WM_Touch messages instead (and do all gesture recognition yourself).

Note that all of this is actually deprecated in Windows 8 (along with all mouse related messages), you're supposed to use WM_Pointer messages now.

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but, do you happen to have any simple example of using WM_Pointer?  Basically I'm after an option to be able to move two (or even more, the more the better) trackbars on a form via multitouch display... And honestly have no idea where to start getting any info...